# Capacitor connected with a DC source

Tags: capacitor, dc

Here is the pure capacitor connected with a pure DC source. The moment switch is closed all the voltage of the source will appear at the capacitor plates causing the current to flow. I wonder what would be the graph of current be? Some says it's exponential others says it's a direc delta function. Can anyone please explain that to me that how current or graph of current will look like in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wonder what would be the graph of current be?

Well, you say it's a "pure capacitor connected with a pure DC source" hence, the current will be infinite amps for an infinitesimally short period. Then the current is zero for evermore.

That sounds similar to what you mentioned in your question: [the Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)